# Joining two select queries from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

The table contains an ID column, valueHeading column and a value column. I want to separate the value column into two new columns called valueHeading1 and valueHeading2 depending on which type of valueHeading the value has.

So I want to join this select:
**Edit: Full join**

```
SELECT ID
      ,valueHeading
      ,value as 'valueHeading1'
FROM table1
WHERE valueHeading = 'valueHeading1'
```

With This select:

```
SELECT ID
      ,value as 'valueHeading2'
FROM table1
WHERE valueHeading = 'valueHeading2'
```

on their respective ID's. How do I do this?

**Edit** to illustrate what I want to do:

Original table:

```
ID    valueHeading    value
0     valueHeading1    a
0     valueHeading2    a
1     valueHeading1    ab
1     valueHeading2    NULL
2     valueHeading1    abcd
2     valueHeading2    abc
```

New Table:

```
ID    valueHeading1    valueHeading2
0          a               a
1          ab              NULL
2         abcd             abc
```

Comment: I added SQLServer tag, as it seems it's the DB you're using :)

Comment: Yes sorry I didnt make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ possible use PIVOT

```
SELECT ID, valueHeading1, valueHeading2
FROM
(
 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.test28
 WHERE valueHeading IN ('valueHeading1', 'valueHeading2')
 ) x
 PIVOT
 (
  MAX(value)
  FOR valueHeading IN ([valueHeading1], [valueHeading2])
  ) p
```

Demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9b89/1/0)

Comment: This looks nice and clean.

Comment: @mdc If you're working with MSSQL, you definitely should use this one.

Answer (score 8):

If you need only join use this. Using case when is elegant way if you don't need join.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ID
          ,valueHeading
          ,value as 'valueHeading1'
    FROM table1
    WHERE valueHeading = 'valueHeading1') AS TAB_1, 
    (SELECT ID
          ,value as 'valueHeading2'
    FROM table1
    WHERE valueHeading = 'valueHeading2') AS TAB_2
    WHERE TAB_1.ID = TAB_2.ID
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like :

```
SELECT ID
      , CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading1' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueHeading1
      , CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading2' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueHeading2
FROM table1
WHERE valueHeading IN ('valueHeading1', 'valueHeading2')
```

If you want to regroup all values on one row for each ID, you can try :

```
SELECT ID
      , MAX(CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading1' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS valueHeading1
      , MAX(CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading2' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS valueHeading2
FROM table1
WHERE valueHeading IN ('valueHeading1', 'valueHeading2')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading1' THEN value ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
OR MAX(CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading2' THEN value ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b2a4/1). I also tried on Oracle 11g and MSSQL 2012, and it works each time.

Comment: I think it should be `value` not `valueHeading`. ie; `CASE WHEN valueHeading = 'valueHeading1' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS valueHeading1`

Comment: Yes I need the value not valueHeading. However this only seems to fill either valueHeading1 or valueHeading2 with values. Not both of them? If I would join the two selects I posted there would be values in both valueHeading1 and valueHeading2 columns, right?

Comment: This fills only one of them and other is null. What do you exactly need?

Comment: @Kaf I need a full join between the two selects. A row  even if only one has a value. If both has values then both values should be there.

Comment: Why don't you try this query with `value` change and see if you get the results? Im not clear what you exactly need yet or are you looking for a `UNION`?

Comment: @X.L.Ant I think your edit is fine...could you confirm it with my edit in the OP.

Comment: I confirm it. I just added a SQLFiddle. I checked on several DB engines, it works every time.

Comment: I was trying to answer your question after realising exactly what you need. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a253/3) which does differently.

Comment: @Kaf That one was easier to look at and understand.

Answer (score 0):

self join could be a simple solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.value as valueHeading1, t2.value as valueHeading2, 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.valueHeading <> t2.valueHeading
```