# how should I join two queries result on same table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following two queries which I have two join.

```
SELECT count(staff_id) FROM employee_kras as e WHERE appraisal_type_id is null
union all
SELECT count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e
where Team_KRA_Status='approved' AND Appraisal_status IS NULL
union all
SELECT count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e where appraisal_status='not submitted' and
    Appraisal_Type_ID IS NOT NULL
union all
SELECT count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e where
    Appraisal_status='submitted' AND Mgr_Rating_id is null
```

with following query:

```
SELECT staff_id, 
CASE WHEN appraisal_status='not submitted' and Appraisal_Type_ID IS NOT NULL 
THEN 'Inprogress' 
WHEN  Appraisal_status='submitted' AND Mgr_Rating_id is null 
THEN 'submitted' 
WHEN Team_KRA_Status='approved' AND Appraisal_status IS NULL 
THEN 'approved' 
WHEN appraisal_type_id is null then 'not started' 
ELSE 'submitted' END AS appraisal_status
from employee_kras ORDER BY staff_id;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  These queries are doing different things.  The first one outputs aggregate counts, the second one outputs all records, from the same table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648405/joining-two-select-queries-from-the-same-table    see this

Answer (score 1):

you cannot join these queries . There is a different level of agregation . You can use the folowing query to have a resulat that you are wainting for  , be careful , I use a Static methode to do the job  :

```
SELECT 'not started' Status , count(staff_id) FROM employee_kras as e WHERE appraisal_type_id is null
union all
SELECT 'approved' Status   , count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e
where Team_KRA_Status='approved' AND Appraisal_status IS NULL
union all
SELECT 'Inprogress' Status , count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e where appraisal_status='not submitted' and
    Appraisal_Type_ID IS NOT NULL
union all
SELECT 'submitted' Status  , count(staff_id) from employee_kras as e where
    Appraisal_status='submitted' AND Mgr_Rating_id is null
```

Comment: I cant select not started,approved,Inprogress and submitted because this value will change after employee progress

Comment: you can check that the conditions in  your seconde query are the same that I put in Mine . If the employee progress , the condition also are changing . and you will have the result that you expect . but if there is a new Stats , you have to change it in the query .

Comment: yaa.Thank you so much it is working but it is displaying column name as not started

Comment: I just modified the query to have a name for a column . I choosed : Status